# Does MongoMapper (or any other Mongodb adapter) have a method like "accepts_nested_attributes_for"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm considering using mongodb on a new project, but before delving in, I'd like to know if it supports some key features. I know you don't need migrations, and you can add embedded objects,...but does all that mean it also behaves as if the 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' method is always there?

Do you know of any other killer features that I should be aware of that would sway me for or against MongoDB?

Here's a recent article I'm aware of, and that others may also be interested in:

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/12/18/why-i-think-mongo-is-to-databases-what-rails-was-to-frameworks/

Comment: I see there've been several views, but no bites...is there any way I can improve the question to motivate...mmm...speakage?

Comment: Perhaps this is a royally dumb question, since Mongo appears to accept json data without requiring special methods. Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the mongomapper guy is working on a solution to this:

http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/browse_thread/thread/e92c35f6e2302687/b9f0860ac83d9b4e?lnk=gst&q=nested#b9f0860ac83d9b4e

http://gist.github.com/275594

Comment: FYI, that's not actually the MongoMapper guy (John Nunemaker). He's said in another thread that he's now working on it, but at least somebody is and hopefully it'll get pulled into the main repository.

Comment: Thanks Emily! I would've gone on thinking that was the case.