# adding a processing custom form field in rails 3.0 with mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I've got a Rails 3.0 project, using mongo with MongoMapper. I've got a model with basic info describing a petstore which has_many pets. A pet is a separate model.

I have a form that lets me create new petstores, but how do I add a field to create a pet at the same time as I create the new store? Right now I have a hacked in solution that accomplishes what I want, but I there's probably a Rails Way to do this, huh? How can I do it properly, so that I can use validations on the form fields and such?

My current solution involves hacking in a form field for the pet manually (added an  tag with name="petstore[pet]" in the form template. This form is handled by petstore_controller's create method, and I added code to create a pet from the form field

Models:

```
class Petstore
  include MongoMapper::Document

  many :pets, :dependent => :destroy

  key :name, String
  key :address, String
end

class Pet
  include MongoMapper::Document

  belongs_to :petstore

  key :petstore_id, ObjectID, :required=>true
  key :type, String, :required=>true
  key :name, String 
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%=form_for @petstore do |f| %>
  <li>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder =>"The name" %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= f.label :address %>
    <%= f.text_field :address, :placeholder =>'The address' %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="petstore_pet">Type of pet</label>
    <input type="text" id="petstore_pet" name="petstore[pet]"> 
  <li>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </li> 
<% end %>
```

petstores_controller.rb

```
def create
  pet = @petstore.pets.build :type => params[:petstore][:pet]
  pet.save if pet

  respond_to do |format| 
    ...
  end
end
```

Similar topics/questions:

- [Rails + MongoMapper + EmbeddedDocument form help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526004/rails-mongomapper-embeddeddocument-form-help)

(I'm not exactly sure how to map that solution onto my question.)

- [Does MongoMapper (or any other Mongodb adapter) have a method like "accepts_nested_attributes_for"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076130/does-mongomapper-or-any-other-mongodb-adapter-have-a-method-like-accepts-neste)

(Accepted answer references a google group thread that is a little over my head...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, there is not a clean, simple way to do this.

Slightly longer answer:

Your controller will attempt to create/update a model by passing it the hash derived from the form.  The key to successfully nesting forms is first to get your form to give you back the correct data. I think you have gotten this part down.  Second, you need to get `PetStore.create` to do "the right thing" with that hash.

In MongoMapper the rules for dealing with the hash are very simple.  It creates and instance of your model and then calls `#{key}= value` for every key/value pair in the hash. For example if `MyModel` is a MongoMapper Document class and I call `MyModel.create(:foo=>"bar",:baz=>5)`  MongoMapper creates in instance of `MyModel` and calls `foo="bar"` and `baz=5` on it.  So long as those methods exist, MongoMapper does not care what they do.  (Note the `key` class method creates these methods for each key.)

To get this all to work you need to create a `pet=` method on PetStore and have it build out a pet model.

This is not by a perfect answer, but it should be enough for you to get something to work.